Next.js server action authentication laravel breeze api
I want to use Next.js application as SPA in an integrated way with Laravel API. There is breeze-next library for this, but the operations performed here are client-side. I want to do auth operations server-side.
The code I wrote for this is below. The request I made to the /api/user endpoint returns the error message User Data { message: 'Unauthenticated.' }. I don't understand the reason, I would appreciate your help.
"use server";

import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { z } from "zod";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

const schema = z.object({
  email: z.string().email(),
  password: z.string().min(8),
});

const getCookieValue = (name: string, cookies: string[]): string | null => {
  const cookieString = cookies.find((cookie) => cookie.startsWith(name + "="));
  if (cookieString) {
    const value = cookieString.split(";")[0].split("=")[1];
    return decodeURIComponent(value);
  }
  return null;
};

export async function getCsrfToken() {
  const response = await fetch(
    `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL}/sanctum/csrf-cookie`,
    {
      method: "GET",
      credentials: "include",
    }
  );

  const cookieHeader = response.headers.get("set-cookie");

  const setCookies = cookieHeader?.split(", ");

  if (setCookies) {
    const xsrfToken = getCookieValue("XSRF-TOKEN", setCookies);
    const sessionKey = getCookieValue("laravel_session", setCookies);

    if (xsrfToken && sessionKey) {
      cookies().set("XSRF-TOKEN", xsrfToken, {
        httpOnly: true,
      });
      cookies().set("laravel_session", sessionKey, {
        httpOnly: true,
      });

      return { xsrfToken, sessionKey };
    }

    return { xsrfToken: null, sessionKey: null };
  }
}

export async function authenticate(_currentState: unknown, data: FormData) {
  const formData = Object.fromEntries(data);
  const parsed = schema.safeParse(formData);

  const { xsrfToken, sessionKey } = (await getCsrfToken()) as {
    xsrfToken: string | null;
    sessionKey: string | null;
  };

  const response = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL}/login`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Accept: "application/json",
      "X-XSRF-TOKEN": xsrfToken,
      Cookie: `XSRF-TOKEN=${xsrfToken};laravel_session=${sessionKey}`,
    } as HeadersInit,
    credentials: "include",
    body: JSON.stringify(parsed.data),
  });

  const cookieHeader = response.headers.get("set-cookie");

  const setCookies = cookieHeader?.split(", ");

  if (setCookies) {
    const xsrfToken = getCookieValue("XSRF-TOKEN", setCookies);
    const sessionKey = getCookieValue("laravel_session", setCookies);

    if (xsrfToken && sessionKey) {
      cookies().set("XSRF-TOKEN", xsrfToken, {
        httpOnly: true,
      });
      cookies().set("laravel_session", sessionKey, {
        httpOnly: true,
      });

      const response = await fetch(
        `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL}/api/user`,
        {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Accept: "application/json",
            "X-XSRF-TOKEN": xsrfToken,
            Cookie: `XSRF-TOKEN=${xsrfToken};laravel_session=${sessionKey}`,
          } as HeadersInit,
          credentials: "include",
        }
      );

      const data = await response.json();

      console.log("User Data", data);
    }
  }

  if (!response.ok) {
    return { message: "Login failed!" };
  }

  redirect("/dashboard");
}


"use client";

import { authenticate } from "@/app/actions";
import { useFormState, useFormStatus } from "react-dom";

export default function Page() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useFormState(authenticate, {
    message: "",
  });

  return (
    <form action={dispatch}>
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required />
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required />
      <div>{state && <p>{state.message}</p>}</div>
      <LoginButton />
    </form>
  );
}

function LoginButton() {
  const { pending } = useFormStatus();

  const handleClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    if (pending) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  };

  return (
    <button disabled={pending} type="submit" onClick={handleClick}>
      {pending ? "Loading..." : "Login"}
    </button>
  );
}


